# transition treemap diagram in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, treemap

I am loading data  from a google spreadsheet that contains the GDP of selected countries from the 1955 to 2012. From this I want to draw a treemap. So far so good.

I've loaded the data through out internal link and formatted into an object that d3 can handle, then got the layout to draw on the screen-all well and good. I've based it on the Mike Bostock tutorial at http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063582.

The problem comes when I try to transition from a set of data from say 1955 to 2010. I'm confident that the function I'm using to generate the treemap layout is working because the initial display is correct. I pass it a date and it creates the treemap structure.

However when I trigger a change the transition seems to occur and the individual squares change size. But when I examine them I realise that they are all wrong and that I seem to have mapped the new set of value onto the wrong countries.

The newstructure looks visually correct but all the names are wrong. So I get things like cyprus having the largest GDP in 2012. Its as if I've got a list in alphabetical order thats having another set of values in order of magnitude applied to the rather that the new value for say the US being mapped the old value.

Going around in circles here as I'm still faily new to d3 so all help gratefully received.

Code looks like this:

```
/*global app:true JST:true d3:true*/

(function (window, $) {

'use strict';

var menuItems = [];
var menuType='measure';
var checboxItems= ['advanced','emerging'];
var ddID = '0';
var model=[];
var yearValue="2012"
var group="gdp";
var treeStruc={
name:[],
children:[]
}

var margin = {top: 25, right: 5, bottom: 5, left: 5},
width = 965 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 650 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var color = d3.scale.category10();



app.spreadsheet.get(function (data) {
// TODO: process the data
menuItems = data.measures
//console.log(data);
//console.log('menuItems', menuItems);
//crete dropdown and use toggle to swich display on and off
$('#dropDown').click(function () {
  $('ul.ddMenuList').toggle();
});
//populate the dropdown menu
for (var k = 0; k <menuItems.length; k++) {
  $('#ddList').append('<li id="dd_' + k + '"><a href="#">'+menuItems[k].menulist     +'</li>');
};
//add functionality to dropDown menu
$('#ddList li').bind('click', function () {
  ddID = this.id.split('_')[1];
      var text = $(this).text();
  //console.log ("ID=",ddID);
  //console.log (text, "Measure=",menuItems[ddID].type);
  $('#ddTitle').empty();
  $('#ddTitle').append(text);
  createCheckboxes()
});

function createCheckboxes() {
//decide which check boxes to populate
if (menuItems[ddID].type==="measure") {
  group=menuItems[ddID].type
  checboxItems=[];
  $.each(menuItems, function (i) {
    if (menuItems[i].type==="group"){
      checboxItems.push (menuItems[i].checkbox);
    }
    //console.log (checboxItems);
  });
}
    else {
  group=menuItems[ddID].type
  checboxItems=[];
  $.each(menuItems, function (i) {
    if (menuItems[i].type==="measure"){
      checboxItems.push (menuItems[i].checkbox);
    }
    //console.log (checboxItems);
  });
}
//Populate the check boxes
console.log ("Populating check boxes");
$('#cbHolder').empty();
$('#cbHolder').append('<form>');
    $.each(checboxItems, function (i) {
  $('#cbHolder').append('<input type="checkbox" id="cb_'+i+'">'+checboxItems[i]);
  $('#cbHolder').append('</form>');
  //console.log ("checkboxItems",checboxItems[i]);
});
changed3 ()

}

//creates an object containing just the advanced countries
treeStruc={name:[],children:[]};
console.log ("group=",group);
$.each(checboxItems, function (k) {
  console.log("Parent",checboxItems[k])
  model=jQuery.grep(data.stats,function(e,i){return e[checboxItems[k]];});
  console.log('model', model);
  treeStruc.children.push({"name":checboxItems[k],"children":[]});
  //Construct the children of 1 big group to be completed to be updated for each sheet
  $.each(model, function (i) {
  treeStruc.children[k].children.push({'name':model[i].countryname,'size':model[i]    [group]});
  });
});



console.log('treeStruc', treeStruc)
Handlebars.createOptionsHelper(data.options);
drawd3 ();
});


function generateTreemapLayout(filter){
  return d3.layout.treemap()
    .size([width, height])
    .sticky(true)
    .value(function(d) { 
      if(d.size[filter] < 0){
        return 0;
      }
  return d.size[filter]; 
    });
  }

function drawd3() {
  console.log ("function drawd3");
  var treemap = generateTreemapLayout('y'+yearValue)



  var div = d3.select("#d3Object").append("div")
    .style("position", "relative")
    .style("width", (width + margin.left + margin.right) + "px")
    .style("height", (height + margin.top + margin.bottom) + "px")
    .style("left", margin.left + "px")
    .style("top", margin.top + "px");

    var node = div.datum(treeStruc).selectAll(".node")
      .data(treemap.nodes)
    .enter().append("div")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .call(position)
      .attr("id",function(d){
        return d.name;
      })
      .style("background", function(d) { return d.children ? color(d.name) : null; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.children ? null : d.name; });

    };
    function position() {
      this.style("left", function(d) { return d.x + "px"; })
          .style("top", function(d) { return d.y + "px"; })
          .style("width", function(d) { return Math.max(0, d.dx - 1) + "px"; })
          .style("height", function(d) { return Math.max(0, d.dy - 1) + "px"; });
}


function changed3() {
    console.log ("function changed3");
    //make a new treemap layout
    var treemap = generateTreemapLayout('y'+1955);
    console.log('treeStruc',treeStruc);
    //redraw the treemap using transition instead of enter  


    var node = d3.select("#d3Object")
    .datum(treeStruc).selectAll(".node")
    .data(treemap.nodes)
    .transition()
    .duration(1500)
    .call(position)

  }

}(this, jQuery));
```

Comment: Nothing springs out to me reading the code. Could you put a complete version somewhere like jsfiddle please?

Answer (score 3):

Many thanks to Tom Pearson my work colleague for this. The problem lies in where the data is bound to the item on the page. When you come to re draw the treemap because the data isn't bound to the div with a nique identifier like the object name it re maps the data to the first item o the list as it where. This means that something like China's gets given Belgium's information. simple solution is as follows Instead of

```
.data(treemap.nodes)
```

use

```
 .data(treemap.nodes,function(d){
  return d.name;
})
```

The are two instances of this in the original drawd3 function them in the changed3 function. Hope that helps anyone stuck with something similar